# Compare two lists of strings using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How can i perform following using Java Streams?

Here I am trying to compare two lists of string. If any of the element matches, in the first match, increment the count, add matched value to matchList and break the loop.

```
List<String> nameList1 = Arrays.asList("Bill", "Steve", "Mark");
List<String> nameList2 = Arrays.asList("Steve Jobs", "Mark", "Bill");

int count = 0;
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String name1 : nameList1) {
    if (nameList2.contains(name1)) {
            count++;
            matchList.add(name1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(count); // 1
System.out.println(matchList); // [Bill]
```

Comment: *I do not want contains because in the following case, contains will match "Steve" and "Steve Jobs"* - That's true for strings only. If you use `nameList1.contains(someString)` it will tell you if the array contains the exact string.

Comment: What will you achieve using streams here? `String result = null; for (String name1 : nameList1) { if (nameList2.contains(name1)) { result = name1; break; }}`.

Comment: *"Got one more condition, Question updated. Please take a look. Thanks."* - Don't do that.  Changing the question is wasting the time of the people who were trying to help you.

Comment: What you *should* do is:  1) Read / pay attention to the comments you have been given.  2) Try to work out the solution to your problem from the answers that you have been given already.  3) If you can't work it out, ask a new Question that refers to this one and adds the new conditions.

Comment: So are you trying to find the first matching name and then stop checking other names?

Comment: Why the incrementing `count` variable? The value can only ever be zero on one, and the size of the resulting `List` would give you the same number.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the existing solution with a loop is just fine.  Simply translating it to a solution that uses streams is not an improvement.

Here's how I would do it.  NB: this is not tested.

```
// Naive version

List<String> nameList1 = Arrays.asList("Bill", "Steve", "Mark");
List<String> nameList2 = Arrays.asList("Steve Jobs", "Mark", "Bill");

List<String> matchList = nameList1.stream()
    .filter(nameList2::contains)
    .limit(1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

count = matchList.size();
```

Note that there is no need to *both* append to a list *and* increment a count.

If you were going to try to parallelize this, then streams *could* help, but you would need to do it differently.

Finally, if you are *really* concerned about performance, and `nameList2.size() == N` is large enough, it will be faster to convert `nameList2` to a `HashSet`.  This turns this from an `O(MN)` algorithm to an `O(M)` algorithm.

(By contrast, parallelizing the naive version only gives you `O(MN/P)` complexity *at best* where P is the number of processes.  And that is making some assumptions, and ignoring potential memory contention effects.)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

If you just want a count of one or zero, for a *first match found* or *no match found*, make a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from the first [list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) with a [predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) testing if the second [list contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) each streamed item from the first list, [limit to the first](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) match found, and returning via a [ternary statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) either number `1` or `0`.

```
int count = 
        List.of( "Bill" , "Steve" , "Mark" )
        .stream()
        .filter( ( String s ) -> List.of( "Steve Jobs" , "Mark" , "Bill" ).contains( s ) )
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent() 
        ? 1 : 0 
;
```

Not that I recommend that one-liner. See below for more practical code. And see the [correct Answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524263/642706) for a variation on this theme.

## Details

Given two lists of `String` objects:

```
List < String > these = List.of( "Bill" , "Steve" , "Mark" );
List < String > those = List.of( "Steve Jobs" , "Mark" , "Bill" );
```

### List of matches

You can get a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of the items that match.

```
List < String > matches = these.stream().filter( s -> those.contains( s ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

### Single match

But you apparently are asking for only the first item that happens to match.

If that is your goal, you use of a `List` for the result, as well as the counter make no sense. You can only ever have one or zero objects as a result.

#### `Optional`

None of the items may match, so we might not get an item back. For this purpose the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class was invented, to cover the case of returning either a single object or no object (null). The `Optional` class protects against a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) from bungled handling of a return value that is NULL.

```
Optional < String > match =                   // `Optional` is a class wrapping another object, the payload, which may be NULL. 
    these
    .stream()                                 // Produce a stream of items from this `List`.
    .filter(                                  // Apply a predicate test against each item produced in the stream. Items that pass the test are fed into a new second stream.
        ( String s ) -> those.contains( s )   // Predicate.
    )                                         // Returns another `Stream`.
    .findFirst()                              // Halts the new (second) stream after producing the first item. Returns an `Optional` object, a wrapper around the payload which may be NULL.
;
```

You can ask the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) object [if it contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent()) a `String` object or [if it is empty](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty()). If not you can [ask for an alternate value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) to use as a default.  You [could throw](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) an [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) if you expect there always to be a match. Or you can perform your own logic in case of an empty `Optional`. See the class doc and search Stack Overflow to learn more about `Optional`.

```
if( match.isPresent() ) {
    System.out.println( "Match found: " + match.get() ) ;
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "these = " + these );
System.out.println( "those = " + those );
System.out.println( "matches = " + matches );
System.out.println( "match = " + match );
```

> these = [Bill, Steve, Mark]
>
> those = [Steve Jobs, Mark, Bill]
>
> matches = [Bill, Mark]
>
> match = Optional[Bill]

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to save the results in `matchList` and `count` you can use stream `peek` method to save the intermediate results

```
List<String> nameList1 = Arrays.asList("Bill", "Steve", "Mark");
        List<String> nameList2 = Arrays.asList("Steve Jobs", "Mark", "Bill");

        final int[] count = {0};
        List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<>();

        nameList1.stream().filter(nameList2::contains)
                .peek(s -> {
                    matchList.add(s);
                    count[0]++;
                })
                .findFirst();

        matchList.forEach(System.out::println); //Bill
        System.out.println(count[0]); //1
```